# BASIC, Can't output any further Strings after calling %d%n?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*; //for %d%n
import java.text.*; //for DecimalFormat


public class Favorite {
public static void main(String[] arguments) {

String itemName = "Golden Beans";
float offerPrice = 314;
float sellPrice = 321;
float value = (sellPrice - offerPrice);
float cashStack = 500_000;
float maxAmount = (cashStack / offerPrice);
float percentageProfit = ((value / offerPrice) * 100);


System.out.println("Approx. Offer Price is " + "\t" + offerPrice);

System.out.println("Approx. Sell Price is " + "\t" + sellPrice);

System.out.println("The potential profit margin is " + value);

System.out.printf("With a cash stack of "
 + cashStack
 + " we can buy "
 + "%.0f%n", maxAmount);


//why can't I add + itemName; it gives me a compile error when using printf. I can add as much text etc before but not after using + "%.0f%n"



System.out.printf("The profit margin of " 
+ itemName 
+ " as a percentage is "
+ "%.3f%n", percentageProfit);
//why can't I add text here; it gives me a compile error when using printf. I can add as much text etc before but not after using + "%.0f%n"

    }
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to print the `itemName` after `maxAmount` in the one print statement?

Comment: YES!! It won't let me

Comment: Please show what you have tried that doesn't works. Based on the syntax you used, this could be explain or not.

Comment: Resolved with this: alernative solution to your code ;

System.out.printf("With a cash stack of " + cashStack + " we can buy " + "%.0f ", maxAmount).println(itemName);

So you can't confuse printf and println usages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alernative solution to your code ;

```
System.out.printf("With a cash stack of "
            + cashStack
            + " we can buy "
            + "%.0f ", maxAmount).println(itemName);
```

So you can't confuse printf and println usages.

Answer (score 0):

Change your print statement to `%s` (for a `String`) instead of `%n` (which is a newline character)

```
System.out.printf("With a cash stack of "
                + cashStack
                + " we can buy "
                + "%.0f %s", maxAmount, itemName);
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete others answers here, when using printf I would avoid concatenating variables in the format string and do something like:

```
System.out.printf("With a cash stack of %.0f we can buy %.0f %s%n", cashStack, maxAmount, itemName);
```

The [syntax for `printf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) is `public PrintStream format(String format, Object... args)`.

When you try to add more text after the second parameter, you're trying to add a String to a PrintStream which can't work in any type cast.

To print both lines with a single call you can do something like this:

```
System.out.printf("With a cash stack of %.0f we can buy %.0f %s%n"
                + "The profit margin of %s as a percentage is %.3f%n", 
                cashStack, maxAmount, itemName,
                itemName, percentageProfit);
```